# How does one implement a basic x86 interrupt manager for video output display?

Tags: x86

My best idea was to reverse engineer the bios modules loaded into memory but i should ask in here first

my super basic bootloader (it outputs 'e' to the screen)

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'e'
int 0x10
jmp $
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

compiled using nasm and then created a virtual floppy on virtual box

```
head -c 1474560 /dev/zero > bootloader.vfd  
dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=test.bin of=bootloader.vfd
```

the resulting image works and now I want to experiment rendering some graphics to the output device.

I've hit a brick wall because there are a lot of factors to consider:

- how to overwrite the IVT already set up by the BIOS?
- how to programmatically select a display device if available?
- how to determine what section(s) of memory are avaliable to make space for code/heap?

Comment: Why do you need to overwrite the BIOS's interrupt vector?  You can simply not use it.

Comment: The simplest approach is to use the BIOS to set a video mode, then write your image data directly to video memory.  Do you have a particular objection to using the BIOS for the mode set?  Also, do you care about getting modes beyond VGA (320x200x256 or 640x480x16)?

Comment: See https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86) for info about the memory map.  A short answer is that assuming a modern machine with at least 1 MB of memory or so, everything from 0000h:0500h to 8000h:0000h is available for your use.  If 510 KiB is not enough then you actually have to query the BIOS for the map of higher memory.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Because i plan on expanding my OS i expect to eventually overwrite some if not all of the BIOS code already set up for you in memory.

My main objection is that i have no idea what the code actually does without reverse engineering it and documentation is hard to find

And yes I really wanna know how to go beyond basic display modes. But if it simplifies learning i can just stick with the basic VGA display while i learn the rest of the internals.

Comment: You can't overwrite the BIOS code, it's in ROM.  You can overwrite the interrupt vector to unhook it, but I don't see any reason why that would be necessary.  Simply never calling the interrupt will ensure just as well that the video BIOS code never runs.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge does that mean that OS' such as windows and linux still retain the BIOS code?

Comment: Yes.  They simply don't ever call it.

Comment: You might prefer to start back in history.  For example, the PC/AT circa 1984, for which you can [read the entire original BIOS source code, fully commented](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/ibm/pc/at/1502494_PC_AT_Technical_Reference_Mar84.pdf).  No need to reverse engineer.